# How can I fetch an array of data from a custom GI using soap contract based web services

Tags: acumatica

I know how to fetch data from a custom Generic Inquiry using standard soap / page-based web services.

Here's my code for standard web services to get the results from a custom GI:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GI000081.Screen context = new GI000081.Screen();
        context.Url = "http://localhost/AcumaticaDB181000062/(W(6))/Soap/GI000081.asmx";

        context.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();

        LoginResult loginResult = context.Login("admin", "Passw0rd");

        if (loginResult.Code != ErrorCode.OK)
        {
            throw new Exception(loginResult.Message);
        }

        GI000081.Content GI000081Content;
        GI000081Content = context.GetSchema();  //.IN202500GetSchema();

       //Here's the code to obtain the GI data:
        string[][] GI000081Data = context.Export
       (new Command[] {
        GI000081Content.Result.AccountID,
        GI000081Content.Result.Address,
        GI000081Content.Result.CustomerID,
        GI000081Content.Result.AccountName
       },
        null,  //This is the filter - none here, so null..
        0,
        false,
        false
       );
    }
```

My request is, can I get an example of C# code for how to do this using the Contract-based web services.  I know how to extend the endpoint and get the wsdl file / service reference to my custom Generic Inquiry, but I don't know the syntax to make the actual call.
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to make sure that you create the entity in the endpoint properly, make sure that the top level entity contain only the Parameters and that it has a sub entity of type details contain all the results. If there is no parameter then it is fine for the top level entity to be empty.

Here is the code sample that I used

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DefaultSoapClient client = new DefaultSoapClient();
        client.Login("admin", "admin", null, null, null);

        try
        {
            BatchPaymentsInq batch = new BatchPaymentsInq
            {
                Result = new BatchPaymentsInqResult[] 
                {
                    new BatchPaymentsInqResult { ReturnBehavior = ReturnBehavior.All }
                }
            };

            var result = client.Get(batch);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            client.Logout();
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

Here is how I extended my endpoint in order to use it with the Contract Based SOAP API

[image: Web Service Endpoint]

So the main entity named BatchPaymentsInq is pointing to the Generic Inquiry screen and will not have any field in it as you have mentioned that there is no parameter.

The sub entity Result is an array of BatchPaymentsInqResult an object created for containing the fields in the result grid of the inquiry.

Comment: I don't follow.  Where does 'Result' come from?  what is 'BatchPaymentsInqResult[]?  Is that an array variable declared somewhere?  Is it inherent in the BatchPaymentsInq Endpoint?

Comment: I added a bit more precision and an image showing how the endpoint entity is structured